# Network error on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking

I have a ubuntu 14.10 server that took a long time in booting up, when it does boot up, it doesn't with network (it gave me long delays in bootup).  `dmesg | tail` gave

```
[  225.013622] init: networking pre-start process (1401) terminated with status 1
[  225.015451] init: networking post-stop process (1405) terminated with status 100
[  228.512454] init: networking pre-start process (1415) terminated with status 1
[  228.514132] init: networking post-stop process (1419) terminated with status 100
```

Did some googling, this problem seems to be related to the file /etc/network/interfaces,  here is the content of the file:  (em1 is the name of the only ethernet interface)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet DHCP

# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
```

I have to hook up a monitor and keyboard,  type `ifconfig em1;  dhclient em1` to get it working.  That's quite inconvenient.   Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I hope you mean `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace "DHCP" with "dhcp" :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet dhcp

# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
```

And restart the network:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I believe restarting networking is deprecated. The correct way is: `sudo ifdown em1 && sudo ifup em1`.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for the tip,  the restart command still works, but it may be better to use yours.